# Удаление EventListener после его вызова

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Создать сообщение - работает. 
Удалить сообщение - не работает. Оно должно удалять только что созданное через "Создать сообщение" событие.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].addEventListener('click', message);

function message(){
 let message = document.createElement('textarea');
 document.body.appendChild(message);
}

document.getElementsByTagName('span')[1].removeEventListener('click', message);
```

```css
span {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
}
 span img {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
 textarea {
  display: block;
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<span>&#43; Создать сообщение  </span>
<span>&#45; Удалить сообщение  </span>
<span>&#9998; Редактировать сообщение  </span>
<span><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/text-icons-1/512/BT_save-512.png" alt="">Сохранить сообщение </span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Удаление EventListener после его вызова. Оно должно удалять только что созданное через "Создать сообщение" событие.

Вот так.

*Если правильно понял, что вы пытаетесь удалить.*

```js
//----------------------------------------------------------------
// Можно так
document.querySelector('.add').addEventListener('click', message);

function message() {
  let message = document.createElement('textarea');
  document.body.appendChild(message);
}
// Можно так 
document.querySelector('.del').removeEventListener('click', message);

//----------------------------------------------------------------
// Кнопка удалить
var del = document.querySelector(".del");
// Вешаем событие
del.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Все созданные textarea
  var textA = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
  if (textA.length > 0) { // Если есть, что удалять
    // Удалить последнее созданное поле
    document.body.removeChild(textA[textA.length - 1]);
  }
})
```

```css
span {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
}

span img {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

textarea {
  display: block;
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<!-------- Лучше так, класс каждому елементу, так читабельней -------->
<span class="add">&#43; Создать сообщение  </span>
<span class="del">&#45; Удалить сообщение  </span>
<span class="edit">&#9998; Редактировать сообщение  </span>
<span class="save"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/text-icons-1/512/BT_save-512.png" alt="">Сохранить сообщение </span>
```